# CoreData relations

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been coding with ruby & ruby on rails. And in rails, when you build relations between models, there always was foreign key(like user_id or post_id). How does coredata works? I didnt add any foreign key, but somehow it works

ps sorry for newbie question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as with Rails Active Record, Core Data is an ORM. You don't need to specify which foreign key (user_id etc) to use, and the ORM will use name conventions to use one. Check the actual DB tables and you will find the foreign_key column there.

Comment: does database migrates self when i add new attributes to core data builder, or do i have to force it somehow?

Comment: You don't need to use migrations while developing, only if you need to update the database after it has been deployed:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration